# Scrolling Listbox Item on Button Click in windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

> I want to scroll listbox on button click place inside of listbox in
>   windows phone using C#

Comment: and what's stopping you?

Comment: only one item scroll at one click

Answer (score 2):

In LongListSelector, there is method for scrollin which is LLS>Scroolto(item), in which you can easily tell which item shoud be focuesed while click. So you can use Longlistselector

Comment: i am used just simple listbox and display some picture in horizontal view in it. Or place two button inside listbox when i want to scroll one picture then i am click on button left and right

Comment: @user2711213 kindly use LLS and try it